# How to get a random combination of rows that sum up to a specific value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb-10.1

The Table I have:

```
+--------+--------------------+
|item_id|        value        |
+--------+--------------------+
|  1     | 1                  |
|  2     | 4                  |
|  3     | 2                  |
|  4     | 6                  |
+--------+--------------------+
```

What the SQL Query Result should be:
A random combination of items that sum up to 10 with a variable number of different items (in this case 2.)

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
|item_id       |        amount      |      sum    |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
|2             |2                   |8            |
|3             |1                   |2            |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

The results show

You get 2 times item 2 (which has the value of 4 so it adds to a sum of 8).

And you get one time item 3 (which has the value of 2)

### This combination sums up to 10.

Is that even possible, when it should not be the same combination always and picked random if there are other possibilitys?

Comment: Can you explain the logic? How do you get the expected result?

Comment: i added some more info, if it helps

Comment: OK, got it. What database engine do you have, and which version? Otherwise I'll consider generic SQL.

Comment: added the mysql tag

Comment: Which version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x. Those are quite different animals.

Comment: 10.1.31-MariaDB I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a single random combination, you can do:

```
select
  *
from (
  select
    a.item_id as item1, 
    x.n as amount1, 
    a.value * x.n as sum1,
    b.item_id as item2, 
    y.n as amount2, 
    b.value * y.n as sum2,
    rand() as r
  from my_table a
  join my_table b on b.item_id <> a.item_id
  cross join (
    select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
    union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 
    union select 9 union select 10) x
  cross join (
    select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 
    union select 9 union select 10) y
  where a.value * x.n + b.value * y.n = 10
) z
order by r -- sorted randomly
limit 1 -- to get only one combination; remove to get them all
```

Every time you run this query it picks a random [different] solution.

The script to create the table and data you mentioned (that I used to test) is:

```
create table my_table (
  item_id int,
  value int
);

insert into my_table (item_id, value) values (1, 1);
insert into my_table (item_id, value) values (2, 4);
insert into my_table (item_id, value) values (3, 2);
insert into my_table (item_id, value) values (4, 6);
```

**EDIT on July 1st, 2019**: As requested, here's an equivalent [shorter] solution using a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression), available in MariaDB since 10.2.2 (see [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/)):

```
with recursive
val as (select 1 as n union all select n + 1 from val where n < 10)
select
  *
from (
  select
    a.item_id as item1, 
    x.n as amount1, 
    a.value * x.n as sum1,
    b.item_id as item2, 
    y.n as amount2, 
    b.value * y.n as sum2,
    rand() as r
  from my_table a
  join my_table b on b.item_id <> a.item_id
  cross join val x
  cross join val y
  where a.value * x.n + b.value * y.n = 10
) z
order by r -- sorted randomly
limit 1 -- to get only one combination; remove to get all 22 answers
```

This solution scales much better if you need to use higher numbers.

Comment: that works exactly as expected!
lets say i want 3 items that result in a sum of 10, do i just add another cross join?

Comment: and if the sum needs to be something else then 10, do you need more union selects?

Comment: @Darkenn Yes, unless you upgrade to MariaDB 10.2 where you can use a [short] recursive CTE to generate the numbers.

Comment: can you show me the 10.2 version? sorry if it's too much to ask, also im not that advanced with sql.

Comment: @Darkenn There it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all such combinations using a self-join:

```
select t1.item_id, t2.item_id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.value + t2.value = 10;
```

This puts the values on columns rather than in separate rows.

Comment: not sure what t2 is, but maybe you understood it wrong. i updated the question

Comment: @Darkenn t2 is a second reference to the table called t. As the answer says, it's a self-join: t is joined onto another copy of itself.

Comment: but it does not include the possibility of having multiple of the same item as the question says

Comment: thats why i said a random combination because you could not output all.

Comment: @Darkenn . . . You can add `limit 1` to get one combination.  However, the results is *arbitrary* rather than *random*.